# square root of ArrayFieldVector<Complex>

Tags: java, arrays, apache-commons

I am using **ArrayFieldVector** class of apache commons.

`ArrayFieldVector<Complex> a=new ArrayFieldVector<>;`

Now I want to create another **ArrayFieldVector** which elements is **sqrt** of **a**. I didn't find sqrt method in that class. So, how should I calculate sqrt?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Math.pow(element,0.5)` on each element of ArrayFieldVector  and add the result in new ArrayFieldVector

Comment: Vectors elements is complex numbers, so Math.pow() doesn't works in this case. There are **sqrt()** method in class Complex(Apache Commons). So I think there should be such method for Vector<Complex>